# gbm::interact.gbm vs. dismo::gbm.interactions

Tags: r, machine-learning, interaction, gbm

**Background**

The reference manual for the `gbm package` states the `interact.gbm` function computes Friedman's H-statistic to assess the strength of variable interactions. the H-statistic is on the scale of [0-1].

The reference manual for the `dismo package` does not reference any literature for how the `gbm.interactions` function detects and models interactions. Instead it gives a list of general procedures used to detect and model interactions. The `dismo` vignette "Boosted Regression Trees for ecological modeling" states that the `dismo` package extends functions in the `gbm` package.

**Question**

How does `dismo::gbm.interactions` actually detect and model interactions?

**Why**

I am asking this question because `gbm.interactions` in the `dismo package` yields results >1, which the `gbm package` reference manual says is not possible.

I checked the tar.gz for each of the packages to see if the source code was similar. It is different enough that I cannot determine if these two packages are using the same method to detect and model interactions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To summarize, the difference between the two approaches boils down to how the "partial dependence function" of the two predictors is estimated.

The `dismo` package is based on code originally given in  [Elith et al., 2008](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1365-2656.2008.01390.x/full) and you can find the original source in the supplementary material. The paper very briefly describes the procedure. Basically the model predictions are obtained over a grid of two predictors, *setting all other predictors at their means*. The model predictions are then regressed onto the grid. The mean squared errors of this model are then multiplied by 1000. This statistic indicates departures of the model predictions from a linear combination of the predictors, indicating a possible interaction.

From the `dismo` package, we can also obtain the relevant source code for `gbm.interactions`. The interaction test boils down to the following commands (copied directly from source):

```
interaction.test.model <- lm(prediction ~ as.factor(pred.frame[,1]) + as.factor(pred.frame[,2]))

interaction.flag <- round(mean(resid(interaction.test.model)^2) * 1000,2)
```

`pred.frame` contains a grid of the two predictors in question, and `prediction` is the prediction from the original `gbm` fitted model where all but two predictors under consideration are set at their means.

This is different than Friedman's H statistic [(Friedman & Popescue, 2005)](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.1679.pdf), which is estimated via formula (44) for any pair of predictors. This is essentially the departure from additivity for any two predictors *averaging over* the values of the other variables, NOT setting the other variables at their means. It is expressed as a percent of the total variance of the partial dependence function of the two variables (or model implied predictions) so will always be between 0-1.

Comment: Does anyone know of a resource to implement section 8.3 of the Friedman and Popescu article linked above to create a null distribution which can be compared to interaction strengths to see if they are significant?