# Using a 'gbm' model created in R package 'dismo' with functions in R package 'gbm'

Tags: r, machine-learning, gbm

This is a follow-up to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29998014/4200318) I asked a while back that was recently answered.

I have built several `gbm` models with `dismo::gbm.step`, which relies on the `gbm` fitting functions found in R package `gbm`, as well as cross validation tools from R package `splines`.

As part of my analysis, I would like to use some of the graphical tools available in R (e. g. perspective plots) to visualize pairwise interactions in the data. Both the `gbm` and the `dismo` packages have functions for detecting and modelling interactions in the data.

The implementation in `dismo` is explained in Elith et. al ([2008](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CDgQFjADahUKEwi447vIrtfIAhUqpnIKHWJmAnk&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcran.r-project.org%2Fweb%2Fpackages%2Fdismo%2Fvignettes%2Fbrt.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHzMnxieJrceH4PPe6qVx_3vo9ROA&bvm=bv.105841590,bs.2,d.bGQ&cad=rja)) and returns a statistic which indicates departures of the model predictions from a linear combination of the predictors, while holding all other predictors at their means.

The implementation in `gbm` uses Friedman`s H statistic ([Friedman & Popescue, 2005](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~jhf/ftp/RuleFit.pdf)), and returns a different metric, and also does NOT set the other variables at their means.

The interactions modelled and plotted with `dismo::gbm.interactions` are great and have been very informative. However, I would also like to use `gbm::interact.gbm`, partly for publication strength and also to compare the results from the two methods.

If I try to run `gbm::interact.gbm` in a `gbm.object` created with `dismo`, an error is returned…

```
"Error in is.factor(data[, x$var.names[j]]) : 
  argument "data" is missing, with no default"
```

I understand `dismo::gmb.step` adds extra data the authors thought would be useful to the `gbm model`.

I also understand that the answer to my question lies somewherein the source code.

My questions is...

1. Is it possible to modify a `gbm` object created in `dismo` to be used in `gbm::gbm.interact`? If so, would this be accomplished by...

   a.  Modifying the `gbm` object created in `dismo::gbm.step`?

   b.  Modifying the source code for `gbm::interact.gbm`?

   c.  Doing something else?

I will be going through the source code trying to solve this myself, if I come up with a solution before anyone answers I will answer my own question.

Answer (score -1):

The `gbm::interact.gbm` function requires data as an argument `interact.gbm <- function(x, data, i.var = 1, n.trees = x$n.trees)`.

The `dismo` `gbm.object` is essentially the same as the `gbm` `gbm.object`, but with extra information attached so I don't imagine changing the `gbm.object` would help.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11376657)

Comment: Didn't have enough reputation to comment.  I'm quite sure it will work if data is specified when calling the function.